# Do offered bounties affect the reputation gain needed for the Yearling badge?

Tags: support, reputation, badges, bounties, yearling-badge

The definition is:

> **Yearling** Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation.

Do the bounties offered in that year subtract from the reputation gained during the year when calculating if the badge was earned?

Comment: I'd question whether the badge was really earned if a bounty will put a user over or under the cusp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reputation you gain doesn't include the reputation you spend for bounties. If you gained 200 points, and you offer two bounties for a total of 200 points, at the end your net reputation is 0.

Comment: Giving that bounties may help improve overall quality shouldn't they be exempt from being subtracted for the yearling calculation?

Comment: Bounties don't help improve the overall quality; they help getting an answer in the cases nobody has provided the answer the OP was expecting.