# Bounty deduction from yearling badge or alternative badge

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badge-request

I saw that in the calculation of the `yearling` badge ( [Do offered bounties affect the reputation gain needed for the Yearling badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146185/do-offered-bounties-affect-the-reputation-gain-needed-for-the-yearling-badge)) the bounties offered are subtracted and the net reputation is taken into account. Now you can be more than `earning at least 200 reputation` and put it in bounties. And if `earning` is to be encouraged, spending should not be punished.

Now it can be argued that bounties improve or don't improve the overall SO experience ( [Do bounties improve overall quality of the posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146638/do-bounties-improve-overall-quality-of-the-posts)), at least to the point that they already allow you to deserve 4 bronze badges.

So is it reasonable for bounties to be deducted from the `yearling` badge calculation? Or to be an alternative `bountiful yearling` for say, spending at least 500 or more reputation on bounties?

Comment: Isn't the usual advice "Don't spend it all in one place"? If you care about the yearling badge, you have to save 4 points a week for yourself. Can't be that hard!